# Legal Financing

Tags: loans, legal

What is the best way to go about financing a legal case?

The Wikipedia article "[Legal Financing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_financing)" was somewhat helpful, but it did not mention how and with whom I would apply for a loan to finance a legal case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a lawyer or law firm who wants to represent you and talk to them.